# Error: Could not resolve .scss file in React

Tags: reactjs, vite

I am using React with Vite and Fluent UI. This is my App.tsx file.

```
import "./App.css";
import * as React from "react";
import { TextField } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField";
import "./TextField.Examples.scss";

function App() {
  return <TextField label="Standard" />;
}

export default App;
```

But I am not able run this App. This is the error that I get.

> X [ERROR] Could not resolve
> "vite-dep-pre-bundle-external:C:/VITE-TYPESCRIPT-REACT/node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/lib/components/TextField/TextField.scss.js"

Any thoughts? I will be happy for any feedback.

Comment: Did you solve this? If so can you please post an answer. Facing same issue